# Excel VBA - Replace Text in Table Column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which pastes dates as text in a column and I have read somewhere, the best solution to convert the text back to dates is to do a search and replace of `"/"`.

If I do this manually in Excel, it works like a breeze. However, when I try to do this with a macro, I do not see the cells being converted to dates.

This is what the macro recorder gave me and what I am trying to use:

```
Range("t_drill[Date]").Replace What:="/", Replacement:="/", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Comment: "somewhere" is wrong, your dates may be separated by dots. And this idea builds on a side effect, not very nice.

Comment: Try to set the `Value` property of each Cell to CDate() of something. That will cause date formatting.

Comment: There are no dots, the dates are always separated with "/" and if I manually run search and replace, I can achieve the required result

Comment: Also, if I manually enter each cell and press "Enter" the text is automatically converted to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using TextToColumns to convert date:

This is for the date format DMY, if you use a different date format then you will have to make adjustments.

```
Range("t_drill[Date]").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("t_drill[Date]"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 4), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

To adjust for different date formats change as required:

> MDY **:=Array(1, 3)**
>
> DMY **:=Array(1, 4)**
>
> YMD **:=Array(1, 5)**
>
> MYD **:=Array(1, 6)**
>
> DYM **:=Array(1, 7)**
>
> YDM **:=Array(1, 8)**

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Value to the return value of CDate. That changes the formatting of the cell, too.

```
Dim c As Variant: For Each c In Range("t_drill[Date]").Cells
    c.Value = CDate(c.Value)
Next c
```

Note: Originally I thought t_drill[Date] is a single cell. I updated my code so that it works for multiple cells.

Comment: It is preferred that you add some explanation along with your code.