# How to create a macro that can apply a formula to a dynamic range of cells, preferably using array?

Tags: excel, vba

I am completely new to VBA, so this task is a bit difficult for me but I bet it is easy for you guys. 
I am trying to create a macro command that can automatically convert a series of dates from text to a date format that excel can recognize. This is a task which I regularly perform, so it would be very time saving to have a macro doing it for me. 
Basically, I regularly download a time series of e.g. the historical price of a stock. The length of the time series varies every time. 
Next I will need to convert the dates from the downloaded data to a format excel can recognize.

To do so I use the following code:

`=DATE(RIGHT(B2,4),MONTH("1 "&MID(B2,4,3)),LEFT(B2,2))`

in the cell adjacent to the first row of the date series.
I then auto-fill this formula to the end of the series.

I have created a macro that performs this task for me, using the following code:

```
Sub FacsetDates()
' FacsetDates Macro
' Turn Factset dates into excel format
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+D

   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=+DATE(RIGHT(RC[-1],4),MONTH(""1 ""&MID(RC[-1],4,3)),LEFT(RC[-1],2))"
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count - 1, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A" & Lastrow - 1)
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:A" & Lastrow - 1).Select
End Sub
```

My problem is that this code only works if the date series start from row 2. 
If the the series is inserted from row 1 the auto-fill will stop one row short and if the series start from row 3, the auto-fill will fill out one row too much (compared to the length of the data series)

I would like a macro that works no matter which row the data series start. 
E.g. I would like the macro to work even if the date series begin at B10. 
I imagine that the solution is to set the data series as an array in VBA and then perform a loop that manipulate each string of text, and then finally paste the manipulated data in the adjacent column. 
I have started producing the following code:

```
Sub FSdate()

 Dim arrMarks() As Long
 Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
 ReDim arrMarks(1 To Lastrow)

Dim i As Long
 For i = LBound(arrMarks) To UBound(arrMarks)
    arrMarks(i) = ActiveCell
 Next i
```

In which I try to first define the array and its size, and then "copy" the string of text from the active cell (being the first row of the data series), but this code fails. 
After having defined the array, I imagined to run a loop that use the DATE function from above to manipulate every single entry in the array. But my current skills in VBA falls short here, and I simply do not know how to proceed.

Can anyone help create such a code?
or even, do you guys have inputs to alternative ways of doing this task?
Probably the initial code can be manipulated to work no matter which row the data series start.

I hope somebody is able and willing to help me!

Comment: Can you show us the text format of the downloaded date, as you may not need to create a new column for the date format conversion (unless you do require a new data column). To also clarify, could the date start from row 1, or possibly any other row number?

Comment: I also recently gave an answer to another similar question, which maybe helpful in your case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56426618/excel-vba-replace-text-in-table-column/56426929#56426929 Just change the range to match your column.

Comment: @5202456
Yes, I can. 
E.g. the date 1 May 2019 would come in the form:

01-MAY-2019

Excel does not recognize this as a date, so I have to apply the provided formula, which does work.

The date could start from any row, because I basically paste it into the sheet from another.

Comment: The accepted answer to this following question will work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56426618/excel-vba-replace-text-in-table-column/56426929#56426929 Make sure you change both ranges, for example Range("B:B") in the code to match you column, this means you will not have to reproduce the data onto a new row and it will be formatted into an excel recognised date.

Answer (score 1):

This is a vary simplified breakdown of @Dave answer, since you want to use the cell you are selecting to start from. First; set your last row by counting the rows in the column to the left from your active cell. Second; set your range from the active cell to the last row variable. Third: write your formula into the range. Note: the `lRow - ActiveCell.Row + 1` adjusts your range based on the activecell row number.

```
Dim lRow As Long
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Offset(, -1).Column).End(xlUp).Row

ActiveCell.Resize(lRow - ActiveCell.Row + 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=+DATE(RIGHT(RC[-1],4),MONTH(""1 ""&MID(RC[-1],4,3)),LEFT(RC[-1],2))"
```

An easier way to accomplish your task; by overwriting the current text would be to use `TextToColumns`

```
ActiveSheet.Columns("F").TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveSheet.Columns("F"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 3), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Columns("F").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The code is both neat and works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If we first look at what's happening:

```
Sub FacsetDates()
' FacsetDates Macro
' Turn Factset dates into excel format
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+D

    ' Enter Formula in the current cell
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=+DATE(RIGHT(RC[-1],4),MONTH(""1 ""&MID(RC[-1],4,3)),LEFT(RC[-1],2))"
    ' Move to the leftmost cell in a contiguous range from the current cell
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    ' Get the row number of the bottom cell in the same column as the now selected cell
    Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count - 1, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Move to the rightmost cell in a contiguous range from the now selected cell
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    ' Fill down from the current cell by the same number of cells in the range from A1 to the last row
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A" & Lastrow - 1)
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:A" & Lastrow - 1).Select
End Sub
```

Where your issue with the range comes in is that ActiveCell.Range("A1:A" & Lastrow - 1) does not refer to rows 1 to x in the sheet, it refers to rows 1 to x **in your range** which starts at row 2 or 3 or whatever.

You will also learn very quickly that changing selections in code is time/resource consuming and is susceptible to bugs creeping in eg if selections change during the running of your code.

I would consider hardcoding the column where you are outputting your formula if it is always going to be the same to and to avoid making selections. You can do this and input the formula directly into column C like so:

```
Sub FacsetDates2()

    Dim Lastrow As Long
    ' Get the row number of the bottom cell in column A
    Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count - 1, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("C2:C" & Lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=+DATE(RIGHT(RC[-1],4),MONTH(""1 ""&MID(RC[-1],4,3)),LEFT(RC[-1],2))"

End Sub
```

EDIT -

Using the active cell and going to the end of the range as defined in column A you could use this:

```
Sub FacsetDates2()

    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim c As Range
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim currentColumn As String

    ' Store a reference to the active cell
    Set c = ActiveCell
    ' Get the row number and column name of the active cell
    currentRow = c.Row
    currentColumn = Replace(c.Address, currentRow, "")

    ' Get the row number of the bottom cell in column A
    Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count - 1, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Range(c.Address & ":" & currentColumn & Lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=+DATE(RIGHT(RC[-1],4),MONTH(""1 ""&MID(RC[-1],4,3)),LEFT(RC[-1],2))"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for getting back to me with an answer.
Your provided code looks very neat, and would definitely be preferable if I always would paste the date series in column B starting from row 2.
But that is not the case, it could easily be so that it is pasted in column c starting from row 10. Hence, I am looking for a more dynamic solution, and that's why I embarked on the whole selection changing in the code.

Comment: @atetzlaff I've edited my answer to allow for starting wherever in the data range